# Membership Renewal with PayPal Standard

Tags: contributions, paypal

I have problem to get PayPal Standard Membership Renewal to work:

- If it's the only payment option, the form doesn't have a submit button, I would expect the PayPal button to appear.
- If I use it with a second option like Pay Later, the form displays error message requesting Credit card number and Expiration dates, despite the fact, that this information would be collected on PayPal's site. [(see screenshots here)](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nyqKGfS7uHslqCXTOrZqaTVzKYTE1joz2Hkpe9kKu8E/pub)

Any ideas?

CiviCRM 4.6.4 + WordPress 4.2.3
updated 7/30 upgraded to 4.6.5

Answer (score 2):

You may want to follow progress on this issue which seems related:
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17082

Answer (score 1):

Membership renewal and auto-recurring memberships with PayPal Standard have been quirky.  Civi 4.4 they worked with some caveats; Civi 4.5 less so.  Civi 4.6 (and the post 4.6 versions of 4.4LTS) work much more smoothly - though there's still improvements being made, both in the 4.6 and 4.7 branches.  Try upgrading a non-live version of your site to Civi 4.6, and I'm almost certain you'll see this issue go away.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quasi answer. I actually run this already on 4.6.4 - silly typo in first post. So in essence, if I don't find it fixed I tomorrow's release - I am just SOL?

Comment: This afternoon, I upgrade the CiviCRM instance to 4.6.5. After I emptied the browser cache, I tested this again. And the issue persists.